# Delete lots of rows while the table is in use

Tags: sql-server, delete-row, sql-server-2014-express

Deleting rows in database is very costly procedure, if you want to delete lots of them.

I've tried running batch deleting using CHECKPOINT per 50000 rows (takes 3-10s) on a table with 20mln rows, deleting roughly half of it, while the table is in use. While it done the job, it slowed down access to database to a crawl, the whole system stopped responding in a timely manner.

What can I do delete old cruft periodically without slowing down the system too much?

Table in mention has very long rows (hundreds of columns), ordered by time (newest are updated/inserted), we often select newest, but deleted oldest.

Comment: What's slowing the database? Is it locking on the table that's your issue? Is your MAXDOP set to zero so you're getting contention for CPU clock time? Have you got a bunch of triggers that are firing when you're deleting the data?

Comment: if most of the table is deleted,why can't use  `select into newtable required records` and drop old table

Comment: @RichBenner it looks like the IO is saturated, not the CPU. MAXDOP is 0, no user-defined triggers.

Comment: @TheGameiswar thanks, that sounds like a good idea, I'll check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copying filtered rows to temp tables, truncating the table and inserting to freshly-truncated table works much better.